# Why am I getting "segmentation fault" when i try to run copy constructor?

Tags: c++, data-structures, circular-list

The copy function executes when I quit the function and then prints the current contents of the circular linked list. What i'm trying to do is to have an object named other point to the original list before it is deleted (which is the original list before the program quits). Then i assign the data from the original list into the nodes of the new list. Since the first or head node is the largest I used while ( p->info != p->next->info ) as the condition to copy all of the contents before the node and then if (p->info == other.first->info) to identify the head node and then make that nodes data or info equal to the head of the node of the copied list.

'''

//Copy constructor function

```
  template <class T>
    void CLList<T> :: copy ( const CLList<T> & other )
    {
       if ( other.first == NULL )
     first = NULL;
   else
   {
  first = new node<T>;
  first->info = other.first->info;

  node<T> *p = other.first->next;
  node<T> *r = first;

  
  while ( p->info != p->next->info )
  {
      r->next = new node<T>;
      r->next->info = p->info;
   if (p->info == other.first->info)
  {
    r->next = new node<T>;
    r->next->info = other.first->info;
  }


// Node 
 template <class T>
  struct node
{
    T info;
     node *next; 
  };
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Describing what your missing code is doing is not enough.  Second, that function is not a copy constructor.  A copy constructor would have the following signature `CLList<T>(const CLLIst<T>& other);` -- what you have is a function called `copy` that just happens to attempt to do a copy.

Comment: tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C `NULL`. Also try and avoid using pointers in the first place.

Comment: As to why you are getting a segmentation fault -- the most obvious reason is that you are mismanaging pointers or accessing a pointer that points to an invalid location.  Since you decided to use pointers, you need to debug your code to find out where you are doing this.  Otherwise, as the original comment suggested, avoid using pointers if you are not ready to debug these issues yourself.

Comment: You should really implement a copy constructor and not just some random `copy()` function.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It is at least missing some closing braces (I count *five* opening braces and only two closing braces). There might be more missing, seeing how your `while` loop makes no attempt to change `p` or the things to which `p` points, hence no attempt to change the truth of its condition (`p->info != p->next->info`).

Answer (score 0):

This code is all wrong for a copy constructor.  The `while` loop is not actually iterating the input list at all, it is just copying the 1st node over and over. Also, the loop should not be comparing `info` values at all.

This code needs to be completely rewritten. Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
template <class T>
CLList<T>::CCList(const CLList<T> &other)
    : first(NULL)
{
    node<T> *p = other.first;
    node<T> **r = &first;

    while (p)
    {
        *r = new node<T>;
        (*r)->info = p->info;
        (*r)->next = NULL;
        r = &((*r)->next);
        p = p->next;

        // for a circular list only:
        if (p == other.first) break;
    }

    // for a circular list only:
    if (r != &first) *r = first;
}
```